# Is there a bidirectional function in Guava?

Tags: java, guava

So, I need function with API like

```
interface BiFunction<A, B> {
    B aToB(A input);
    A bToA(B input);
}
```

Does Guava provided smt like this. If no, what names you would suggest for `aToB`/`bToA` methods?

Comment: Yeah, I can use two different functions for this purpose.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, there isn't anything like this in Guava currently. Something like it may be coming (see [this issue](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/issues/detail?id=177), as well as [this issue](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/issues/detail?id=219) for some related discussion).

For names, I don't know what would be best but I'd prefer something like `apply` and `applyInverse` over `aToB` and `bToA`.

Answer (score 6):

As of late 2014, Guava 19.0 has it:

https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/base/Converter.html

```
B b = Converter.convert(a);
A a = Converter.reverse().convert(b);
```

You need to implement the methods:

```
protected abstract A    doBackward(B b)
protected abstract B    doForward(A a)
```

Comment: Guava has migrated to github and the link above no longer works.  Here's the new link: 
https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/base/Converter.html

Answer (score 2):

As for suggested names, it depends on how generic you want to go.  Some existing examples are:

```
interface Codec <I, O> {
    public O encode(I in);
    public I decode(O out);
}

interface Format <R, F> {
    public F format(R raw);
    public R parse(F formatted);
}
```

If you want it to be super generic, I would just use `aToB` and `bToA` as you suggested.  Don't make them overloads since you're using Generics, and don't use `toA` since you're not converting the function itself, you're converting an argument.